# Seq head and tail

Tags: f#

Is there a one-liner way to do implement `nextLine`?

```
let s = ref seqOfLines
let nextLine() =
  let hd = Seq.head !s
  s := Seq.skip 1 !s
  hd
```

`seqOfLines` is assumed to be infinite

Comment: It is a really bad idea to use augmenting of sequences like `s := Seq.skip 1 !s` because it creates a new sequence object on top of the other, so your algorithm ends up in O(n^2). Correct me if I´m wrong.

Comment: Why do you want the `nextLine` function in the first place? Why not just iterate over the sequence you have which results in a pure function. You wouldn't even make this sort of thing in C#. If you insist on what you are doing, you should properly use `s.GetEnumerator()` and use that in your `nextLine` function.

Comment: You can look at the source code here: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L1438 It does create a new sequence, does a bunch of memory allocations, etc. Since you know you only want to move one step each time, you're best bet is to call MoveNext yourself.

Comment: @Chris Smith Cool insight :) I can see you know a lot about F#, but can you tell me, why it is not just mappings to `Enumerable.Skip` etc.? instead of programming those twice.

Comment: @lasseespeholt Intentional design decision. Enumerable.Skip requires the .NET framework 3.5 or higher, which we didn't want to do for the first release of F#. Requiring a higher runtime makes installing it a pain in the ass, hurts adoption, etc. Taking a dependency on a 100MB redist isn't worth the cost of not reimplementing methods like Enumerable.Skip. (Once F# has been out a few years this might get revisited...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is to utilize the underlying `IEnumerator<String>`. It isn't quite a one-liner, but it appears to be a bit cleaner than the implementation you have. (Doesn't rely on mutable, properly uses the .NET idioms.)

Essentially you get the [IEnumerator<'a>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx) interface from the sequence, and then just loop on calling MoveNext. This will work fine on an infinite sequence.

```
> let getNextFunc (seqOfLines : seq<'a>) =               
-     let linesIE : IEnumerator<'a> = seqOfLines.GetEnumerator()
-     (fun () -> ignore (linesIE.MoveNext()); linesIE.Current);;

val getNextFunc : seq<'a> -> (unit -> 'a)
```

To use, just pass `getNextFunc` a sequence, and it will return your nextLine function.

```
> let sequenceOfStrings = seq { for i = 0 to 10000 do yield i.ToString() };;

val sequenceOfStrings : seq<string>

> let nextLine = getNextFunc sequenceOfStrings;;  

val nextLine : (unit -> string)

> nextLine();;
val it : string = "0"
> nextLine();;
val it : string = "1"
> nextLine();;
val it : string = "2"
> nextLine();;
val it : string = "3"
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, I think you're trying to approach this too imperatively, and as a result, you're going to end up writing some funky code and losing the benefits of function programming.

You might benefit by re-writing your function so it takes `current state` and returns `value * next state`. This will keep your function purely functional. You also might find it easier to convert your infinite `seq` to a `LazyList` instead (you need to reference the F# PowerPack for this), so you don't have to touch the underlying enumerator directly:

```
> open LazyList
let seqOfLines = Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i) |> LazyList.ofSeq
let nextLine = function Cons(x, xs) -> x, xs | Nil -> failwith "Empty list";;

val seqOfLines : LazyList<int>
val nextLine : LazyList<'a> -> 'a * LazyList<'a>

> nextLine seqOfLines;;
val it : int * LazyList<int> = (0, seq [1; 2; 3; 4; ...])
> nextLine (snd it);;
val it : int * LazyList<int> = (1, seq [2; 3; 4; 5; ...])
> nextLine (snd it);;
val it : int * LazyList<int> = (2, seq [3; 4; 5; 6; ...])
> nextLine (snd it);;
val it : int * LazyList<int> = (3, seq [4; 5; 6; 7; ...])
```

Answer (score 1):

[FSharpx.Collections](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Collections/reference/fsharpx-collections-seq.html) has some useful/efficient functions such as Seq.tail, Seq.Head and Seq.UnCons that might be useful if you want to decompose a Seq into head and tail.